# Ubuntu Touch on Nexus 5 Camera Crashes

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I installed Ubuntu touch on my Nexus 5 using multirom on Android. So far it works well,  but the camera doesn't work.

I reinstalled both the Ubuntu rom and the camera app. The logs from the camera app are below. I've searched Google for variants of "Ubuntu touch shm camera",  but found nothing enlightening.

Do you have any advice on where I can start looking to solve this?

paste.Ubuntu.Com/10229637

Comment: I was using the devel version, which says it's a vivid release. I installed the utopic rom (just utopic, not utopic-rtm or anything like that) and now the camera works. Could this be a regression?